# Spring 3.2 and Cache Abstraction missing EhCache implementation

Tags: spring, ehcache

I am migrating our code to **Spring 3.2** version (from **3.1.3**) and I've got an issue with Spring Cache Abstraction.

We use EhCache implementation of `CacheManager` and its configuration is quite simple:

```
<cache:annotation-driven />

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache" />
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:config-location="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
```

My problem is that I am missing `EhCacheCacheManager` class and corresponding factory bean in `spring-context jar`. I suppose they moved implementation to some other module, but I can't find where exactly.

Comment: what do yr bean decalrations look like now ?

Comment: they are the same, i just updated my maven config and included `spring-context-support` dependency

Comment: doh! thanks ... missed adding the dependcy

Answer (score 56, accepted):

According to [Appendix C. Migrating to Spring Framework 3.2](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/migration-3.2.html),

> "the EHCache support classes in the org.springframework.cache.ehcache package moved from the spring-context module to spring-context-support".

Answer (score 12):

Updating the Maven pom.xml file worked for me.

Properties:

```
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
```

Dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: this is not the tiptop very best idea and apparently answered _after_ the correct one.

Answer (score 9):

Using [oss.sonatype.org](http://oss.sonatype.org), you can search for a class by name and find in which artifacts it's contained, when they are indexed: https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;classname~EhCacheCacheManager.

As SwapnilS has answered, it's in spring-context-support.