# upgraded to spring 3.2 but mail has seemingly disappeared?

Tags: java, spring, email, maven

Just upgraded to spring3.2 - but mail has disappeared AFAIK.

It is not mentioned in the [offical guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/migration-3.2.html).Where has it gone :

[image: where has it gone]

My pom look like this : 
[image: soring-core]

everything else works for me except [cache manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956224/spring-3-2-and-cache-abstraction-missing-ehcache-implementation), but there is an explanation for that.

Comment: Looking at your profile, it would seem that you've been here long enough, and both asked and answered enough questions to realize that *posting a picture of a random section of your POM* is unlikely to get you any reasonable answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I needed this additional jar, same as ehcache support (but not mentioned in guide ?)

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```